# Why does my lambda expression compile while the equivalent method reference does not? Is generics the problem or am I the problem?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, lambda, method-reference

I am trying to use method references with generic classes and have noticed that I can make it work with the equivalent lambda expression, but not with method references. I'm wondering if someone can point out why or tell me what I'm doing wrong...

What I was trying to accomplish when I ran into this issue was to be able to have different builders for different things. The builder receives raw data and a schema containing method references and instructions on when those methods should be called.

I created sandbox code to identify the problem I was having:

```
public class Builder<T extends List> {
    public void doA(T list) {
        System.out.println("doA");
    }
}

public class CarBuilder extends Builder<ArrayList> {
    public void doB(ArrayList list) {
        System.out.println("doB");
    }
}
```

If I create the schemas like this:

```
public class Schema {
    BiConsumer<? extends Builder, ? extends List> methodReference;

    public static Schema builderSchema = new Schema(Builder::doA);
    public static Schema carBuilderSchema = new Schema(CarBuilder::doB);
    
    private Schema(BiConsumer<? extends Builder, ? extends List> methodReference) {
        this.methodReference = methodReference;
    }
}
```

It does not compile:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project Sandbox: Compilation failure
com/sandbox/Schema.java:[11,56] incompatible types: invalid method reference
    method doB in class com.sandbox.CarBuilder cannot be applied to given types
      required: java.util.ArrayList
      found:    com.sandbox.Builder,java.util.List
      reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

If I change it to use lambda expressions instead, it compiles:

```
public class Schema {
    BiConsumer<? extends Builder, ? extends List> methodReference;

    public static Schema builderSchema = new Schema((Builder builder, List list) -> builder.doA(list));
    public static Schema carBuilderSchema = new Schema((CarBuilder builder, ArrayList list) -> builder.doB(list));
    
    private Schema(BiConsumer<? extends Builder, ? extends List> methodReference) {
        this.methodReference = methodReference;
    }
}
```

From what I've read, I thought this was exactly the same as above!?

Comment: Not sure, but the use of raw types might be getting in the way. What happens if you use `List<?>`, `ArrayList<?>` and `Builder<?>` instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Method references and explicitly-typed lambda expressions are treated differently.

Let's simplify the example to just:

```
public class JavaClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Consumer<? /* extends Object*/> a = JavaClass::f; // error
        a = (String s) -> JavaClass.f(s); // works
        Consumer<String> b = JavaClass::f;
        a = b; // also works
    }

    static void f(String s) {}
}
```

This code has the same issues as your code with `CarBuilder` and `ArrayList`.

To determine whether a method reference is compatible with a functional interface type, we first need to figure out the *function type* to check against. For a method reference, this function type is derived from the target type `Consumer<?>`. This turns out to be a function returning `void`, and taking an `Object` as parameter. See [Function Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.9) for details.

Then, in a similar way as overload resolution, we need to [resolve](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13.1) the method reference - find a suitable method with the name `f` that is compatible with the function type. Here, the method reference is treated as if it were a method call with an argument of type `Object`, i.e.

```
void temp(Object o) {
    // if overload resolution successfully finds an overload for this call,
    // that overload is what the method reference is referencing
    JavaClass.f(o);
}
```

Of course, `JavaClass.f` takes a `String`, so this does not work, and that's the reason for the error.

---

Explicitly-typed lambda expressions are handled differently. For a functional interface type with wildcards like `Consumer<?>` here,  [Functional Interface Parameterization Inference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-18.html#jls-18.5.3) is used to find the function type to check against. This basically takes into account the parameter types you explicitly stated in the lambda expression. This time, we find the function type to be a function taking a `String` and returning `void`. The lambda expression is trivially compatible with that.

If the lambda expression had been implicitly-typed, `(s) -> JavaClass.f(s)`, it would have been treated in a similar way to a method reference.

So to use a method reference here, you would need a cast:

```
Consumer<?> a = (Consumer<String>)JavaClass::f;

new Schema((BiConsumer<CarBuilder, ArrayList>)CarBuilder::doB);
```

See also [Type of a Lambda Expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.3) and [Type of a Method Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13.2).

---

That said, using a `? extends` bound on a `Consumer` doesn't make much sense - the consumer wouldn't be able to consume anything except `null`, without unchecked casts. Remember  [producers `extends`, consumers `super`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super).

You should probably stop using [raw types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321/5133585) too.

Comment: Thank you!! Your answer led me to understand what the problem was and fix it properly (I believe). As you said, keeping it as-is and using unchecked casts would not be a good solution, although, indeed, it would work. I added the two generic types to the Schema definition as well `Schema<T, U>`, which makes the BiConsumer<T, U> more 'aware' and fixes the problem.